how to stop otherwise( ) in python polars when using a when( ) expression?
This is my dataframe:
┌─────────────────────┬──────────┐
│ date                ┆ price    │
│ ---                 ┆ ---      │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64      │
╞═════════════════════╪══════════╡
│ 2023-12-20 14:10:00 ┆ 2039.105 │
│ 2023-12-21 14:45:00 ┆ 2045.795 │
│ 2023-12-22 15:10:00 ┆ 2069.708 │
│ 2023-12-26 06:45:00 ┆ 2064.885 │
│ 2023-12-27 18:00:00 ┆ 2083.865 │
│ 2023-12-28 03:05:00 ┆ 2088.224 │
│ 2023-12-28 15:00:00 ┆ 2080.245 │
│ 2023-12-29 07:10:00 ┆ 2074.485 │
└─────────────────────┴──────────┘

My main issue was to find prices close to each other and group them together in Polars, but I didn't find any useful code. So, I decided to do it outside of polars.
Now I have this problem with Polars that I want to categorize price based on a nested list I have separately. I am using the below code:
for i ,group in enumerate(resistance_groups):
            highs = highs.with_columns(
                pl.when(pl.col('price').is_in(group))
                    .then(i+1)
                    .otherwise(None)
                    .alias('groups')
            )

Which resistance_groups is like this:
[[2064.885, 2069.708, 2074.485], [2080.245, 2083.865, 2088.224]]
And highs is the above dataframe.
The result of above code in first loop is :
┌─────────────────────┬──────────┬────────┐
│ date                ┆ price    ┆ groups │
│ ---                 ┆ ---      ┆ ---    │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64      ┆ i32    │
╞═════════════════════╪══════════╪════════╡
│ 2023-12-20 14:10:00 ┆ 2039.105 ┆ null   │
│ 2023-12-21 14:45:00 ┆ 2045.795 ┆ null   │
│ 2023-12-22 15:10:00 ┆ 2069.708 ┆ 1      │
│ 2023-12-26 06:45:00 ┆ 2064.885 ┆ 1      │
│ 2023-12-27 18:00:00 ┆ 2083.865 ┆ null   │
│ 2023-12-28 03:05:00 ┆ 2088.224 ┆ null   │
│ 2023-12-28 15:00:00 ┆ 2080.245 ┆ null   │
│ 2023-12-29 07:10:00 ┆ 2074.485 ┆ 1      │
└─────────────────────┴──────────┴────────┘

And in second loop, it is:
┌─────────────────────┬──────────┬────────┐
│ date                ┆ price    ┆ groups │
│ ---                 ┆ ---      ┆ ---    │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64      ┆ i32    │
╞═════════════════════╪══════════╪════════╡
│ 2023-12-20 14:10:00 ┆ 2039.105 ┆ null   │
│ 2023-12-21 14:45:00 ┆ 2045.795 ┆ null   │
│ 2023-12-22 15:10:00 ┆ 2069.708 ┆ null   │
│ 2023-12-26 06:45:00 ┆ 2064.885 ┆ null   │
│ 2023-12-27 18:00:00 ┆ 2083.865 ┆ 2      │
│ 2023-12-28 03:05:00 ┆ 2088.224 ┆ 2      │
│ 2023-12-28 15:00:00 ┆ 2080.245 ┆ 2      │
│ 2023-12-29 07:10:00 ┆ 2074.485 ┆ null   │
└─────────────────────┴──────────┴────────┘

As you see the first loop results are removed from df.
Can anyone suggest a way to either stop the .otherwise() or any other way to categorize the price column?
I tried to use multiple when-then expressions too and it didn't work too,
using another column wasn't that good either.
And just in case: removing  .otherwise( ) means setting the values to null.

What is the criteria for "prices close to each other"? There should be a way to do that part in Polars.

I was thinking if price is in X% higher or lower than refrence price it counts. But I couldn't find a way in polars so i just tried some for loops instead to get it

Ah okay. At the very worst, one could use a cross-join. It seems like it could be a worthwhile question on its own - I imagine you'll get several answers.

Hope so (more reputation more fun) but there is already an answer.

Yes but the separate question of generating resistance_groups natively in Polars seems like it would also be useful to solve.

Alternatively to @DeanMacGregor's solution, you could use pl.coalesce instead. This leverages that pl.when().then() evaluates to None if the when case is not True.
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.coalesce(
            pl.when(pl.col("price").is_in(group)).then(index+1)
            for index, group in enumerate(resistance_groups)
        )
        .alias("groups")
    ) 
)

shape: (8, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬──────────┬────────┐
│ date                ┆ price    ┆ groups │
│ ---                 ┆ ---      ┆ ---    │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64      ┆ i32    │
╞═════════════════════╪══════════╪════════╡
│ 2023-12-20 14:10:00 ┆ 2039.105 ┆ null   │
│ 2023-12-21 14:45:00 ┆ 2045.795 ┆ null   │
│ 2023-12-22 15:10:00 ┆ 2069.708 ┆ 1      │
│ 2023-12-26 06:45:00 ┆ 2064.885 ┆ 1      │
│ 2023-12-27 18:00:00 ┆ 2083.865 ┆ 2      │
│ 2023-12-28 03:05:00 ┆ 2088.224 ┆ 2      │
│ 2023-12-28 15:00:00 ┆ 2080.245 ┆ 2      │
│ 2023-12-29 07:10:00 ┆ 2074.485 ┆ 1      │
└─────────────────────┴──────────┴────────┘


thanks it works just as needed. i just wondered is there a website, book or sth that i can use for learning more practical polar coding? using documents is  overwhelming !!

@Far1D I think that someone is working on a polars book. You can find the link to the current version in the Discord (linked on GitHub). Otherwise, I'd just suggest being curious and trying to implement things in polars.

Answer to question as asked
You need to initialize highs with groups column as all null and then in your when add a criteria that groups is null and finally change the otherwise to return itself. Like this
highs=highs.with_columns(pl.lit(None,pl.Int32).alias('groups'))
for i, group in enumerate(resistance_groups):
            highs = highs.with_columns(
                pl.when((pl.col('price').is_in(group)) & pl.col('groups').is_null())
                    .then(i+1)
                    .otherwise(pl.col('groups'))
                    .alias('groups')
            )

Improved way
You should do this as a join rather than looping. Try this out
(
    highs
    .join(
        pl.Series('price',resistance_groups).to_frame()
        .with_row_index('groups', offset=1)
        .explode('price'), 
        on='price', how='left'
        )
)


If its purely about stopping the otherwise to overwrite a column's value, this is likely the way to go.

@Hericks yeah it's definitely an anti-pattern XY question so I edited in a way to not do any looping at all. Of course they're still doing some anti-pattern to generate their resistance_groups in the first place so what's one more I guess.

@dean-macgregor thanks for the answer and edits on question. as i mentioned in the question i tries using another column. i also checked the result of the code. if you pay attention to how the when() works here you see that it doesn't work

I see that I initially missed a parenthesis and I am ignoring the difference between your groups starting at 1 and that this starts at 0. Is there something else that "doesn't work"?

nah everything else is okay. thanks
